# Angular 4 application not working on IE 11 (polyfills.ts , maven frontend plugin)

Tags: angular, maven, internet-explorer, polyfills

I'm working on an angular 4 application packaged with maven and jenkins and wish is supposed to work on a liberty core server.

After the build, I got all *.bundle.js files but the application only works on chrome and firefox. I've already updated my polufills.ts to enable IE.

When starting the application on IE I got the below error :

```
SCRIPT5007: La valeur de la propriété « webpackJsonp » est null ou non définie, pas un objet Function
```

Here's my packege.json file :

```
{
  "name": "historage-ui",
  "version": "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --output-hashing none",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "deploy": "npm publish",
    "load": "npm install"
  },
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.4.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.26",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.5.2"
  }
}
```

and the polyfills.ts

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following to support `@angular/animation`. */
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/** ALL Firefox browsers require the following to support `@angular/animation`. **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
/**
 * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
 */
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

Comment: Your are showing the TS files, did you compile them to JS? Also, Are you sure that your `polyfills.js` are loaded before the `main.bundel.js` ?

Comment: Yes, as I mentionned, my files are transpiled into .js files.
I also checked that polyfills.bundle.js is called before main.bundle.js.